# Third Normal Form (3NF)

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization, third-normal-form

I have these two tables.

[image: table]

If I make sure that they are in 3NF is this the correct way? My answer:

StaffDetails(**StaffID**, SName, DOB, DivisionNo*)
Division(**DivisionNo**, DivName, DivSupervisorID)
StaffProject(**StaffId***, **ProjectNo***, SName, ProjectName, HoursAssigned)
Project(**ProjectNo**, ProjectName)

The primary keys are bolded but what is the reason behind an asterisk?

Comment: Please ask 1 question per post. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Re "is this right": Show the steps of your work following your reference/textbook, with justification--not all terms/notations are standard & we don't know exactly what algorithm/method you are following & we want to check your work but not redo it & we need your choices when an algorithm allows them & otherwise we can't tell you where you went right or wrong & we don't want to rewrite your reference. Please see [ask], [help], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Basic questions are SO faqs, research before considering asking & reflect research in posts.

Comment: Underlines & asterisks are not standard notations. Use block quote format (read the edit help) to identify the parts of this post that you copied & tell us where you copied them from & tell us what those things were defined to mean by the presentation you copied them from. Don't copy/quote without giving credit. Don't say "my" when you didn't create it yourself, that is plagiarism. Please clarify via edits, not comments. [ask] [help] [meta] [meta.se]

Comment: The concept of **functional dependency** and **transitive relation** would be helpful in 3NF validation, the point is to test whether any non-key column can determine the value of another non-key column.

Comment: @Ham It's transitive FD, not transitive relation. And 3NF is iff/when no non-CK set of columns transitively functionally determines a non-CK column.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, its not quite 3NF as you duplicate `SName` and `StaffProject` in the `StaffProject` table.

The tables should probably be:

**StaffDetails**

| Column | Data Type | Constraints |
| --- | --- | --- |
| StaffDetails | VARCHAR2 | Primary Key |
| SName | VARCHAR2 |  |
| DOB | DATE |  |
| DivisionNo | INT | Foreign Key(Division) |

**Division**

| Column | Data Type | Constraints |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DivisionNo | INT | Primary Key |
| DivName | VARCHAR2 | (Probably Unique) |
| DivSupervisorID | VARCHAR2 | Foreign Key(StaffDetails) |

**StaffProject**

| Column | Data Type | Constraints |
| --- | --- | --- |
| StaffID | VARCHAR2 | Composite Primary Key, Foreign Key(StaffDetails) |
| ProjectNo | VARCHAR2 | Composite Primary Key, Foreign Key(Project) |
| HoursAssigned | NUMBER | Check > 0 |

**Project**

| Column | Data Type | Constraints |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ProjectNo | INT | Primary Key |
| ProjectName | VARCHAR2 | (Probably unique) |

---

As for your notation questions, that is a convention your tutor appears to be using but is not necessarily globally recognised so you would be best asking them; however it appears that primary keys are underlined and foreign keys have an asterix next to them.

`StaffProject` would have columns that are both part of a composite primary key and a foreign key so would have both notations.

Comment: Hi @MTO, composite primary key means foreign key that being used as primary key isit?

Comment: And i noticed within the Division table, the DivSupervisorID is known as Foreign Key to the StaffDetails table? Is that mean i should indicate it with an asterisks?

Comment: Yes it should, as it is a foreign key referred to the StaffDetails PK

Answer (score 4):

A column or columns on the primary key of a table can also be a foreign key of another one.

In your example it seems that:

- (StaffId, ProjectNo) is the PK of `StaffProject`.
- `StaffId` is **also** an FK against the table `StaffDetails`; that's why it has an asterisk.
- `ProjectNo` is **also** an FK against the table `Project`; that's why it has an asterisk on itself.

If you want your model to be 3NF you'll need to remove extra dependencies:

- In this case `DivName` and `DivSupervisorID` are redundant and should be removed from the table `StaffDetail`.
- `ProjectName` and `SName` are also redundant in `StaffProject`. You must remove them for the model to be compliant with 3NF.

Comment: So if a foreign key of a table is being used as a primary key on another table it should be underlined with an asterisks is that what you meant?

Comment: When a table does not have a PK on its own, but uses keys of other tables (or a combination of) as its PK, then it's called a "weak entity". The notation varies and the asterisk seems to be a notation in this particular case only.